# c # To transmit large amounts of data using a Web service

Tags: c#, web-services

I need to transfer **1 GB** using a web service. I think to transfer piecewise using msmq. Maybe there is a way to take it easy?

Comment: What do you mean transfer using webservice? Are you posting this data to the WS? or is it a response?

Comment: I posting this data to the WS

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12551/Sending-Files-in-Chunks-with-MTOM-Web-Services-and

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you CAN break the data up in smaller chunks, then do. Web services aren't designed to transport that much data in one go, so even though it's possible, it's gonna be a bumpy ride.

But the world doesn't work in an efficient way, so here's what you do:

write the data as binary to a local file.
 2. Create a streamwriter that writes to your webservice using a streamreader to read from the file.
 3. If anything happens, catch the exception and try to resume from where your file pointer is.
 4. If you can modify the webservice, have it read the data and write to a binary file, catching any errors and trying to write any new data on resume to the file at the current pointer.

The trick is going to be to figure out how to tell the service you're trying to resume an interrupted request.

If this isn't clear, I'll try to expand some more.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to transfer 1 GB using a web service. I think to transfer piecewise using msmq.

I want to transport people with a car. I Think of using a plane.

Get it? Either web service, or MSMQ. They do not magically mix.

THAT SAID: Web service, alrge data = bad idea. Even JSON has overhead. STreaming, non streaming? That is a LOT of open variables, and in most cases the web service here makes relatively little sense.

Up (sent to service) or down (to the service)? More questions - I would not really want a 1gb upload to a web service.

If you have to, splice the data and make an api to ask for all "parts" and then get part by part - that also allows a progress bar to be shown. Your software MUST handle re-requests for parts due to failures which MAY happen in transit.

I would seriously consider not using a web service here if the data is binary and just go with a REST api, at least for downloads. Likely also for uploads. Lots depends on all the stuff you did not even know how to ask for or did not bother to describe.

Answer (score 0):

You can make some service to first creat buffer in destination next split data and send it through service, then finalize it.